# Ionic 2: invalid page component: null

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, ionic2

In my ionic 2 iOS application I'm getting this error on some tab clicks.
invalid page component: null nav-util.js:23. Because of this page contents are not being loaded properly. Can anyone suggest what may be the reason and also solution for the same. Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you declare them on ``app.module.ts`` ?

Comment: @raj I dint get what is the declaration.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare components in `declarations` of `app.module.ts`. Here is an example.

```
import { UserHuntedPage } from '../pages/feed/user-hunted/user-hunted'
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    UserHuntedPage
  ]
  ....
})
```

Comment: By default it is been declared. Mine is just one page app, I have kept the same default component as HomePage It looks like this, declarations: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage
  ],